# Using bind_cols(), can I pass a name for the columns being added or do I have to rename them after?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I hope there's an easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out. I'm calculating trip lengths and defined "started" and "ended" columns for the calculations. I want to add a column that includes the result.

I'm using tidyverse and lubridate.

```
started <- cyc_trip_data$started_at
ended <- cyc_trip_data$ended_at

trip_duration <-
  duration(as.double(ended - started))
```

While this gets me the data I want, when I add it with bind_cols() to the df, it names the new column "...n" where n is the column number.

```
cyc_trip_data <- cyc_trip_data %>%
  bind_cols(trip_duration)
```

So far I have used rename() and relocate() to move the column and rename it. I hope someone might have an idea for a more elegant solution so I can save a step.

I want to name the columns after the variable I define, e.g. "trip_duration" above.  I know .name_repair is an argument that can be passed in bind_cols() but I don't quite understand if it even applies here and when I tried using it, I still ended up with "...n"

```
cyc_trip_data <- cyc_trip_data %>%
  rename(trip_duration = ...12) %>%
  relocate(trip_duration, .after = ended_at)
```

Comment: `bind_cols(trip_duration = trip_duration)` should work.

Comment: Why not just `cyc_trip_data %>% mutate(trip_dur = duration(ended - started))`?

Comment: Thank you both! Both of those solutions should work. @r2evans, I had to add as.double to that but it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
cyc_trip_data <- cyc_trip_data %>%
  bind_cols(trip_duration = trip_duration)
```

AND

```
cyc_trip_data <- cyc_trip_data %>% 
   mutate(trip_dur = duration(as.double(ended - started)))
```

did the trick. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!